# Distribution of distributions

Tags: distributions, sample

Could anybody point me towards material for dealing with data when your sample points are distributions in themselves? To be more specific each data point I am sampling has a mean and a variance, so I am basically drawing them from a distribution of distributions.

I couldn't really find anything not the least because I don't know the right terminology for what I am looking at.

[Update] Description of data:
I have GPS points that come with an estimated measurement of the variance for each point.

Comment: I do not find the term  -  distribution of distributions. In Wikipedia.  please  mention the sources for it you have had seen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than your observations being distributions, it sounds like you have some uncertainty or variability about your observations. This kind of observations can be modelled using hierarchical models. For example, you can say

\begin{eqnarray}
y_j &\sim& Normal(\mu,\sigma^2),\,\,\, j=1,...,n,\\
\mu &\sim& F,\\
\sigma^2 &\sim& G.
\end{eqnarray}

where $F$ is a distribution on ${\mathbb R}$ and $G$ is a distribution on ${\mathbb R}_+$. A discussion on the choice for $F$ and $G$ can be found in:

> [Prior distributions for variance parameters in hierarchical models](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/taumain.pdf)

**Update** If you have the estimated variance, you can still use hierarchical models. Take a look at Chapter 5 of the book:

> [Bayesian Data Analysis](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Bayesian-Analysis-Edition-Chapman-Statistical/dp/158488388X)

and the aforementioned paper.

Consider also the case when the observations are measured with a certain error. This is, an observation $y_j$ means that you are actually observing $y_j\pm \epsilon$. In this case the treatment might be a little different. For a proper modelling of your data, you  need to clearly understand the measurement mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for analysis which can treat *imprecise input data*? I would look for terms like *metaanalysis* and:

```
statistics working with imprecise input parameters
statistics working with imprecise input data
statistics fuzzy input data
```

Here are some resources:

http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~adje/uploads/vstte_13.pdf

http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/17415977.2012.675505#.VDepYmd_vcw

http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=778922

http://sci2s.ugr.es/keel/pdf/keel/articulo/gfs-extendido-IEEE.pdf

http://gnedenko-forum.org/Journal/2008/022008/RATA_2_2008-09.pdf

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167947302001160